# How long does it take a villager's health to fully deplete?

Tags: virtual-villagers-2

In Virtual Villagers 2: The Lost Children I can cause my villagers to become sick by feeding them a certain stew recipe. But once they are sick, I can't seem to see a visible depletion of their health bar. How long does it take a sick villager's health to deplete all the way and cause death?

Answer (score 1):

After researching this question for a long time, I came across a post, to which the person answered:

"Note that there's **no way to tell exactly how much health they have**; the health bar, like the skill bar, changes in increments, and nobody who knows is saying exactly how that is tracked or rounded, though I could likely find the value with an external utility, if anybody really cared. I don't see that it would help me play the game, though, to know if an empty health bar is really a zero, or just 1 out of 100 health points, rounded down to the closest increment on the health bar."

[(Source)](http://www.ldwforums.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=149712&page=all)

NOTE: This applies to all Virtual Villagers games

Otherwise, this question doesn't have a definite answer. Based on my experience, the number is most likely random (ie. between a range of time) and also dependent on other factors, such as population.

Comment: Well my villager seems to just be stuck on the status of "Sick" and after multiple days does not seem to have any of its health being depleted. Sickness is supposed to cause death, yet my people don't seem to be dying.

Comment: It would make sense for sickness to imply death, but that's apparently not the case. They should still weakened when they are sick (maybe the point of sickness?)

Comment: Do you want your villagers to die? If so, you could try making them continuously do an activity, like fishing without providing treatment. See if the health bar goes down then!

Comment: When doing research before asking this question I read a site that said that when they were sick their health depletes. And yes, I want them to die (I have been stuck at max population for a few years now). I'll try to make the sick ones do work and report back here if they start getting any weaker.